# Difference in Behaviour Between Azure Web App Services

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

We have two App Services which both appear to be configured identically. Both appear to be using the same service plan, in the same location, and are on the same Pay-As-You-Go subscription. Both are running the same ASP.NET Web Application, pointing to the same database. Both Web Applications also have identical directory structures outside of the Web Application (wwwroot) where required. The only difference between the two is that 'App Service A' has been assigned a custom domain and SSL certificate (which is the user's primary method of access).

We've noticed two fundamental differences however in the way these App Services behave, and cannot understand why -

a) On 'App Service B', when making changes to the Web.Config via the Azure App Service editor, the changes are applied instantally. However, on 'App Service A', a restart of the App Service is required.

However, and more importantly -

a) On 'App Service B', any files uploaded by the user via the Web Application appear in the correct place under the application directory structure (D:\Home\AppSubDir...), and are visible when accessing the site via FTP. However, on 'App Service A', while the Web Application appears to be able to access the uploaded files, they are not visible via FTP or the Kudu tools. When the App Service is restarted, the Web Application then also cannot see the files.

Re-implementing the application using Azure Files/Blob Services is not an option available to us right now given current deadlines. Also, we cannot fathom why if the existing functionality works correctly on one site, why should it differ on another.

We also need files to be preserved outside of the "wwwsite" structure for the sake of application logging (being stored in D:\Home\LogFiles\AppSubDir..). Again, on 'App Service A', these files are not visible.

It seems there's a difference on configuration somewhere between the two sites, but haven't trouble trying to identify exactly what that/those configuation option(s) within Azure could be. Any guidance much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have local cache enabled?

Comment: At the browser - no. But files are given unique identifiers after uploading before storing on the server, then returned to the client on request using the unique id as the filename. We're not even seeing the files being stored on the server using the unique id via FTP/Kudu.

Comment: I'm referring to the App Service local cache feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-local-cache-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Ebbo (above) has kindly answered this, for anybody else who experiences the same issue. It was simply a case of removing the "WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_SETTING" Application Setting in the Azure Portal, under the "Application Settings" section. After which, reset the App Service and normal behaviour returns.

[image: Click the 'X' to the right to remove]

/Edit - more documentation on the Azure "Local Cache" can be found here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-local-cache-overview